# expected expression before '{' token

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, mapkit

please i didn't understand what wrong whith my code :

```
float lng = [[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"ssiphone_longitude"] floatValue];
float lat = [[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"ssiphone_latitude"] floatValue];

location2D={latitude:lat,longitude:lng};//this line which cause error
MKCoordinateSpan span={latitudeDelta:0.2,longitudeDelta:0.2};
MKCoordinateRegion region={location2D,span};
[mapView setRegion:region];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

`lng` an `lat` have really the longitude and latitude value, i maked sure on the console :) thx for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
location2D = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){ .latitude = lat, .longitude = lng };
```

or simply:

```
location2D = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){ lat, lng };
```

Comment: Hi, i got that error when i try to declare the location2D in the .h file, so when i declare it directly in .m file, it works, can you please tell me why ?? thx

Answer (score 0):

is better to use built-in macros & functions:
so:

CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lng, lat);

don't worry about speed... these functions are very efficient.